# LINQ on List with lot of nested List

Tags: c#, linq

I have got trouble with nested lists. So I have 3 class:

```
public class Class1
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<Class2> Class2List {get;set;}
}
public class Class2
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<Class3> Class3List {get;set;}
}
public class Class3
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to select all Class3.Name where Class2.Name = "something" from Class1 and important that the result will be **IEnumerable string** . How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LINQ expressions can have multiple nested `from` clauses:

```
// nested from clauses
var names = from c1 in myClass1List
            from c2 in c1.Class2List
            where c2.Name == "something"
            from c3 in c2.Class3List
            select c3.Name;
```

---

For completeness, here are two variants using method syntax:

```
var names = myClass1List
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.Class2List.Where(c2 => c2.Name == "something"))
    .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Class3List.Select(c3 => c3.Name));

var names = myClass1List
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.Class2List
        .Where(c2 => c2.Name == "something")
        .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Class3List
            .Select(c3 => c3.Name)));
```

Comment: You can also add method syntax version of this query with `SelectMany`, that will make answer even better)

Comment: @Eduard: Thanks for the edit, I've been using VB.NET for too long. ;-)

Comment: Than you for fast answer. The solution is grate.

Comment: No problem. I'm sure everyone understood :). I myself have a long Delphi history behind me. It's just that some young programmers might be looking at the code character by character.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<string> listNames = Class1.Where(f => f.Class2List.Where(g => string.Compare(g.Name, "something") == 0)).Select(h => h.Name).ToList()
```