# How do you create nested groups with linq via lambda/method expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is it possible? For example, how would you rewrite the working code below with a lambda expression?

```
public void QueryNestedGroups()
{
    var queryNestedGroups =
        from student in students
        group student by student.Year into newGroup1
        from newGroup2 in
            (from student in newGroup1
            group student by student.LastName)
        group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
}

// Three nested foreach loops are required to iterate  
// over all elements of a grouped group. Hover the mouse  
// cursor over the iteration variables to see their actual type. 
foreach (var outerGroup in queryNestedGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DataClass.Student Level = {0}", outerGroup.Key);
    foreach (var innerGroup in outerGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tNames that begin with: {0}", innerGroup.Key);
        foreach (var innerGroupElement in innerGroup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0} {1}", innerGroupElement.LastName, innerGroupElement.FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean `method syntax`:

```
var queryNestedGroups = students.GroupBy(x=>x.Year, (key,g1)=>
                              g1.GroupBy(x=>x.LastName, (key2,g2)=>
                              g2.GroupBy(x=>x.Year)));//Because the group1.Key is exactly Year;
```

If you don't want to use `Year` hard-codedly. Try this instead:

```
var queryNestedGroups = students.GroupBy(x=>x.Year, (key,g1)=> 
                        g1.Select(x=>new{key,x})
                          .GroupBy(x=>x.x.LastName, (key2,g2)=>
                        g2.GroupBy(x=>x.key, x=>x.x)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = myClass1List
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.Class2List.Where(c2 => c2.Name == "something"))
    .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Class3List.Select(c3 => c3.Name));

var names = myClass1List
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.Class2List
        .Where(c2 => c2.Name == "something")
        .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Class3List
            .Select(c3 => c3.Name)));
```

See more: [LINQ on List with lot of nested List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736513/linq-on-list-with-lot-of-nested-list)

Comment: The OP seems to want to convert `query syntax` to `method syntax` not `SelectMany`

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to post on this question but since there's no answer been posted I'm leaving a post here for those landing here seeking similar problem. I had this same problem converting similar linq query to lambda expression.

Here's how you can do it:

```
var res1 = students.GroupBy(th=>th.Year)
                           .SelectMany (grp1 => grp1.GroupBy (th => th.LastName), (grp1, grp2) => new {grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2})
                           .GroupBy (temp0 => temp0.grp1.Key, temp0 => temp0.grp2);
```

see the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372419/nested-groups-linq-query-vs-groupby-extension-method) which helped figuring out the solution.