# Nested Groups Linq query vs Groupby extension method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, grouping

I was trying to convert below nested grouping using `GroupBy` extension method.

```
        var res = from th in teamHistories
                  group th by th.Date into grp1
                  from grp2 in
                      (from th in grp1 group th by th.Event)
                  group grp2 by grp1.Key;
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<KeySelector, IGrouping<KeySelector, Object>>`; Which produces a tree like structure -

```
FirstGroup -> Key(Date) 
   Elements - SecondGroup -> Key(Event)
       Elements - (TeamHistory) ..
```

But when I tried to write similar query using GroupBy extension method it seems to work differently. According to signature of Groupby method it returns
`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Means if I would try to do nesting it returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<KeySelector, Elements>>>` which ,ofcourse, would produce non-desired results.

Here's what I tried:

```
    var res1 = teamHistories.GroupBy(x => x.Date, (key, g1) =>
                                    g1.Select(x => new { key, x })
                                         .GroupBy(x => x.x.Event, g => g));
```

Question -

1. Is this correct way of doing such nesting? Because the results I'm getting are different. It's returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<KeySelector, Elements>>>` instead of `IEnumerable<KeySelector, IGrouping<KeySelector, IGrouping<KeySelector, Object>>>`.
2. Are there any limitations with `GroupBy` extension methods compared to `Group by` clause in Linq query?

Here's the complete [snippet](https://gist.github.com/vendettamit/01b523386d89d6d5e6a8) if someone wants to reproduce the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first query (in your [snipped](https://gist.github.com/vendettamit/01b523386d89d6d5e6a8)) would be this way using method syntax:

```
   var res1 = teamHistories.Where(th => th.TeamName.ToLower() == "xxx")
                           .GroupBy(th=>th.Date)
                           .SelectMany (grp1 => grp1.GroupBy (th => th.Event), (grp1, grp2) => new {grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2})
                           .GroupBy (temp0 => temp0.grp1.Key, temp0 => temp0.grp2);
```

About your second question there is no limitation using method syntax. In fact your first query using query syntax must be translated into method calls for the .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled,  so both are semantically identical, just that query syntax is syntactic sugar that helps to make queries simpler and easier to read.

Comment: It's returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<KeySelector, IGrouping<KeySelector,Elements>>>>`. Return type is wrapped in  additional enumerable. I had to use an additional loop to get the actual result. Do you know if somehow it can be avoided?

Comment: Awesome!! Now I have to analyze it carefully how you converted it. +1.